# How to use Cross Validation for Multioutput Regressor in Sci-kit?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, cross-validation

first my setup:
X is my feature table. It has 150 000 features and 96 samples. So 150 000 columns and 96 rows.

y is my target table. It has 4 labels and of course 96 samples. So 4x96 (columns x rows).

After splitting into train and test data I'm using MLPRegressor. Based on the documentation of Sci-kit it is an native multioutput regressor. So I can use it to predict my four desired output values with a new sample of 150 000 features .
My code:

```
mlp = MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(2000, 2000), solver= 'lbfgs', max_iter=100)
mlp.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

And then I'm using cross validation.

```
cross_validation.cross_val_score(mlp, X, y, scoring='r2')
```

The output is a list with 3 entries (parameter cv=3).
I don't really get how my 4 labels get represented by these 3 values.
I expected something in a format like this:
label 1: 3 entries, label 2: 3 entries and the same with label 3 and 4.
So I'm getting the R^2-Value for all my labels three times for different splittings of test and train data.

Am I missing something? Do I need to use Multioutputregressor?
[(See doc here)](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputRegressor.html#sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputRegressor][1])

And [Here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html) the documentation of cross validation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

First thing is if you are actually using `cross_validation.cross_val_score()`, then you should replace that with `model_selection.cross_val_score()`. Module `cross_validation` has been deprecated and removed from latest version of scikit.

Now coming to why you are only getting a single score for all your outputs and not individual entries is because thats how the default value of scorer is set.

You have used scoring `'r2'` which is [documented here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html). In that, there is an option to change the result if the input is multi-output (as your case) by using the

> **multioutput** : 
>   Defines aggregating of multiple output scores. Array-like value
>   defines weights used to average scores. Default is “uniform_average”.
>
> ‘raw_values’ : Returns a full set of scores in case of multioutput
>   input.
>
> ‘uniform_average’ : Scores of all outputs are averaged with uniform
>   weight.
>
> ‘variance_weighted’ : Scores of all outputs are averaged, weighted by
>   the variances of each individual output.

You see that the default value is `'uniform_average'`, which just averages all the outputs to get a single value, which is what you are getting.

Comment: Okay I understand that, but that would mean I need to use

r2_score(y_true, y_pred, multioutput='raw_values')

Is there a possibility to do that in cross-validation?

Comment: @DurmusHarman No. `cross_val_score` internally uses [`cross_validate`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html), which specifies that a single value be returned from the scorer.

Comment: @DurmusHarman If the multi-threading capabilities of `cross_val_score` are not required (looking at your code, you are not using them), you can just have your custom cross-validation. Split the data into folds, fit the estimator on train data and get the scores on test data easily.